# Cipher Function Producing Unwanted Results in the Last Character of Output

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

I have been spending all day trying to figure out what I did wrong with this enciphering function I created.

The function works by taking in a keyword which it then converts to an ASCII values and then takes that value and formats it into something that will work with an alphabetical index `eg: A= 0, B= 1, C= 2, etc...` It then converts all of the plain text using the same method. After that it shifts over the characters of the plain text and then adds the characters value from the keyword iterating over the keyword in a loop until it is done encrypting the plain text.

It works for all my tests except for one which went like this:

> ```
> Keyword is BaZ
> ```

**input:**

```
plaintext: BaRFoo
```

**output:**

```
ciphertext: CaQGoh
```

but the desired output is

```
ciphertext: CaQGon
```

I am using the following encipher function:

```
void encipher(char* plainText, char*key)
{
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    char alphabeticalIndex[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    int currentKeyChar = 0;

    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(plainText); i < n; i++)
    {
            // check if the end of they key has been reached, if so then reset it
            if(currentKeyChar >= strlen(key)) currentKeyChar = 0;


            if(isalpha(plainText[i]) == false) printf("%c", plainText[i]);

            if(isupper(plainText[i]))
            {
                // find the cipher character as an int then add it as the key to captialCharNum
                int capitalCipherCharNum = ((int) key[currentKeyChar] - 65);
                int capitalCharNum = (((int) plainText[i] - 65) + capitalCipherCharNum) % 26;

                printf("%c", toupper(alphabeticalIndex[capitalCharNum]));
            }

            if(islower(plainText[i]))
            {
                // same as it was for capitals but in this case its lowercase
                int lowerCipherCharNum = ((int) key[currentKeyChar] - 97);
                int lowerCharNum = (((int) plainText[i] - 97) + lowerCipherCharNum) % 26;

                printf("%c", tolower(alphabeticalIndex[lowerCharNum]));
            }
        currentKeyChar++;
        }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `capitalCharNum = (((int) plainText[i] - 65) + capitalCipherCharNum) % 26;` --> add `'A'`

Comment: do you mean `capitalCharNum = (((int) plainText[i] + 'A') + capitalCipherCharNum) % 26;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
            int lowerCipherCharNum = ((int) key[currentKeyChar] - 97);
```

When `key[currentKeyChar]` is ***uppercase***, `lowerCipherCharNum` is negative, resulting in your cipher value being wrong. To fix the problem you need:

```
            int lowerCipherCharNum;
            if (islower (key[currentKeyChar]))
                lowerCipherCharNum = key[currentKeyChar] - 'a';
            else
                lowerCipherCharNum = key[currentKeyChar] - 'A';
```

This will correct your expected output.

While there is nothing wrong with using *array indexing* to work your way down each string, using *pointer arithmetic* can greatly simplify your code. (you also have unnecessary and repeated calls to `strlen` that should be removed (or at least minimized by computing the length of `key` once rather than every time you check it.))

An example of how using pointer arithmetic can simplify your logic (and shortening your variable names because I don't like to type), you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void encipher (const char *plaintext, const char *key)
{
    const char *aidx = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
               *p = plaintext,
               *k = key;

    printf ("ciphertext: ");

    while (*p) {
        if (isalpha (*p) == 0) printf ("%c", *p);

        if (isupper (*p)) {
            /* find the cipher character as an int then add it as the key */
            int ccicn = (*k - 'A');
            int ccnum = (*p - 'A' + ccicn) % 26;

            putchar (toupper (aidx[ccnum]));
        }

        if (islower (*p)) {
            /* same as it was for capitals but in this case its lowercase */
            int lcicn = islower (*k) ? *k - 'a' : *k - 'A';
            int lcnum = (*p - 'a' + lcicn) % 26;

            putchar (aidx[lcnum]);
        }
        p++;
        if (*k)  k++;
        if (!*k) k = key;
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* don't use printf for one-character */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    const char *s   = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "BaRFoo", 
               *key = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "BaZ";

    encipher (s, key);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/encipher
ciphertext: CaQGon
```

(**note:** the comment `/* don't use printf for one-character */`)

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Below is an "edited" version of your `encipher` function with a few additional thoughts in comments and the code spaced a little wider (which you may appreciate more as your eyes get older)

```
/* if plainText and key are not modified, pass them as 'const char *' */
void encipher (const char *plainText, const char *key)
{
    /* place variables before executed code if you have the option...
     * (just increases portability to older compilers (like Win7))
     */
    char alphabeticalIndex[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int currentKeyChar = 0;
    size_t keylen = strlen (key);

    printf ("ciphertext: ");

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen (plainText); i < n; i++)
    {
        // check if the end of they key has been reached, if so then reset it
        if (currentKeyChar >= (int)keylen) currentKeyChar = 0;

        if (isalpha (plainText[i]) == 0) putchar (plainText[i]);

        if (isupper (plainText[i]))
        {
            // find the cipher character as an int then add it as the key
            int capitalCipherCharNum = ((int) key[currentKeyChar] - 65);
            int capitalCharNum = (plainText[i] - 65 + capitalCipherCharNum) % 26;

            putchar (toupper (alphabeticalIndex[capitalCharNum]));
        }

        if (islower (plainText[i]))
        {
            // same as it was for capitals but in this case its lowercase
            // int lowerCipherCharNum = ((int) key[currentKeyChar] - 97);
            int lowerCipherCharNum;
            if (islower (key[currentKeyChar]))
                lowerCipherCharNum = key[currentKeyChar] - 'a';
            else
                lowerCipherCharNum = key[currentKeyChar] - 'A';

            int lowerCharNum = (plainText[i] - 97 + lowerCipherCharNum) % 26;

            putchar (tolower (alphabeticalIndex[lowerCharNum]));
        }
        currentKeyChar++;
    }

    putchar ('\n');     /* don't use printf for one-character */
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. Those subtle little bugs can be a bear to find. There is a great little article that may help you in the future, [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)`  (here I caught the negative values stepping through the code with `gdb` -- an hour investment is all it requires to become proficient with it -- well worth the price of admission...)

Comment: I will definitely keep these tips in mind. I thank you once more!